# update the map_server

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know a way to update the map that map_server uses? AFAIK, the map is set to the contents of an image file as soon as the node is launched, then remains static for the life of the node.
My situation is as follows: I have two nodes this job *mapper* and *map_server*. *Mapper* records ultrasonic range measurements into a png file, and has a service for saving updated versions of the map. How can I push updates of the map to my *map_server* node??
Will I have to relaunch the *map_server* node every time? Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155111/update-the-map_server/) by [TimboInSpace](https://answers.ros.org/users/11216/timboinspace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2014-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you're doing it too complicated. If your Mapper node already has a map there is no need to send that to the map server. Just publish it from the Mapper node at the /map topic.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TimboInSpace](https://answers.ros.org/users/11216/timboinspace/) on 2014-04-19**:
You're right. I changed the Mapper node to publish its own OccupancyGrid, and this was a lot simpler. It's working quite well now.

**Comment by [Avonic](https://answers.ros.org/users/26092/avonic/) on 2016-03-05**:
But what if I need to publish an occupancy grid only after some editing, can I have map_server continuously publishing?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-03-07**:
Yes...............

**Comment by [Avonic](https://answers.ros.org/users/26092/avonic/) on 2016-03-08**:
In fact, it just publish the same occupancygrid without updating it even if the grid has changed